# golang how to access promoted type

Tags: go, reflection

I have a 'common' structure promoted within two specific structures. For example:

```
type common struct {
    name string
}

type apple struct {
    common
}

type orange struct {
    common
}
```

Details specific to `apple` and `orange` are omitted.

I have a type-specific map of each, e.g., `map[string]*apple` and `map[string]*orange`.

I am trying to make a single function that can extract the `common` pointers. From what I've tried so far, reflection appears required.

My function is:

```
func getFruitArray(theMap interface{}) []*common {
    m := reflect.ValueOf(theMap)
    cf := make([]*common, 0, m.Len())
    for _, mk := range m.MapKeys() {
        v := m.MapIndex(mk)
        cf = append(cf, v.Interface().(*common))
    }

    return cf
}
```

This function fails at `cf = append(cf, v.Interface().(*common))` with:

`panic: interface conversion: interface {} is *main.apple, not *main.common`

Is there a way to access the promoted struct `common` without specifically referencing `apple` or `orange` in this function?

[playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/eDbpD2e58de)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Burak's answer which makes the reasonable compromise of having to call a method to receive the value.

Regardless, below is a solution which uses reflection as you planned. Note that `common` needs to be `Common` (exported field) else the reflect package cannot read it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type Common struct {
    name string
}

type apple struct {
    Common
}

type orange struct {
    Common
}

func getFruitArray(theMap interface{}) []*Common {
    m := reflect.ValueOf(theMap)
    cf := make([]*Common, 0, m.Len())
    for _, mk := range m.MapKeys() {
        v := m.MapIndex(mk)
        f := v.Elem().FieldByName("Common")
        cf = append(cf, f.Addr().Interface().(*Common))
    }

    return cf
}

func main() {
    appleMap := make(map[string]*apple)
    orangeMap := make(map[string]*orange)

    a1 := &apple{}
    a1.name = "my apple"
    appleMap["test"] = a1

    o1 := &orange{}
    o1.name = "my orange"
    orangeMap["test2"] = o1

    f1 := getFruitArray(appleMap)
    for _, c := range f1 {
        log.Printf("f1: %s", c.name)
    }

    f2 := getFruitArray(orangeMap)
    for _, c := range f2 {
        log.Printf("f2: %s", c.name)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/FrkRnu_G2Xd

Answer (score 2):

You don't need reflection. One way is to use an interface:

```
type common struct {
    name string
    tag  string
}

func (c *common) GetCommon() *common {return c}

type WithCommon interface {
   GetCommon() *common
}
```

Then you can do:

```
func getFruitArray(theMap map[string]WithCommon) []*common {
   cf := make([]*common, 0, theMap.Len())
   for _,k:=range theMap {
      cf=append(cf,k.GetCommon())
   }
   return cf
}
```

But you also have to do:

```
 appleMap := make(map[string]WithCommon)
 orangeMap := make(map[string]WithCommon)
```

Comment: This answer changes the requirements. The inbound map to getFruitArray is now a non-specific type. (Also it doesn't compile, I think you intended https://go.dev/play/p/M6HwgtuszyK

Comment: I was going by the code that used the key of the map as the common object. You are right though, the rest of the code uses `map[string]*apple`. I changed my answer based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are doing you could use the [`unsafe`](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe@go1.17.6) package. But if you don't then don't.

```golang
func getFruitArray(theMap interface{}) []*common {
    m := reflect.ValueOf(theMap)
    cf := make([]*common, 0, m.Len())
    for _, mk := range m.MapKeys() {
        v := m.MapIndex(mk).Elem() // use elem to dereference the pointer
        t := v.Type()

        // If you know that common is always the first field
        // then you can just use v.Field(0). But if common's
        // position is not guaranteed then use a loop like below.
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            sf := t.Field(i)
            if sf.Anonymous && sf.Name == "common" {
                f := v.Field(i)
                // 1. get the address of the common field
                // 2. convert it first to unsafe.Pointer
                // 3. then convert it to *common
                c := (*common)(unsafe.Pointer(f.UnsafeAddr()))
                cf = append(cf, c)
            }
        }
    }

    return cf
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/XMi86jj2wiW

Comment: This answer avoids exporting the common type. Cool.